# Create a "teleportable" object in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible?
For instance say I have a house , and I want to teleport to it via the `/tp username destination`
Could I assign a variable to the co-ordinates? For instance

> destinationvariable= 100x100x100 ,

Then I could go `/tp username housevariable`

Comment: /tp username 200 200 200

Comment: I want to teleport to a co-ordinate inside a variable as my layout will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't make variables. But you can do this by summoning armor stands which you can teleport to.

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Destination",Invulnerable:1b,NoGravity:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomNameVisible:1b}
```

where ~ ~ ~ is where you are standing (You can change it to the XYZ co-ords)

FEATURES
1. You will be able to see the nametag in the place where the Armorstand is (but not armor stand)
2. The Armorstand will not fall so it doesn't matter where you summon it.
3. You can TP with a simple command
4. The player can't break this.

TP:

```
/tp @p @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Destination]
```

BTW, you need a command block to enter all the [tags] when making the armor stand BUT not when teleporting.